# CSS & HTML : Where to set main height(parent) of the page?

Tags: html, css

I want to ask where to put the main parent height of the web page?

For example i have constructed my page like this:

```
<body>
   <div class="page-wrapper">

   </div>
</body>
```

I want my `<body>` height to `auto` so what ever the height of the page-wrapper it will fit but at the same time I want also the page-wrapper to have height `auto` so it will response to its child `<div>`s. But setting there height `auto` will not give children height's percents(%) value.

Example:

```
<body>
   <div class="page-wrapper">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="height:25%;">

       </nav>
   </div>
</body>
```

Setting `.navbar` height to 25% is not working. I just want to ask what is the proper way or any tricks to add height to a web page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a relatively positioned element, the `top, left, right, bottom` properties specify the relative distance to shift the generated box. Remember that in the case of relative positioning they complement one another, so that top:1em and bottom:-1em means the same, and it’s not meaningful to specify both top and bottom (or left and right) for the same element, because one of the values will be ignored.

But in the case of absolute positioning. Here, all four properties can be used at the same time, to specify the distance from each edge of the positioned element to the corresponding edge of the containing block. You can also specify the position of one of the corners of the absolutely positioned box—say by using top and left—and then specify the dimensions of the box using width and height (or just use no width and height if you want to let it shrink-wrap to fit its contents).

This code may meet your need：

```css
.page-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.navbar {
    height: 25%;
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.content {
    height: 300px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>

   <div class="page-wrapper">

       <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
       </nav>
       <div class="content"></div>

   </div>

</body>
```

Comment: adding the positions works for me but i realy appreciate it if there is a little bit explantion thanks upvoted anyways

Comment: I edit the answer for some  explanations, and refer to the w3c standard https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning

Answer (score 0):

i thnk u are using bootstrap in bootstrp navbar navbar-default is bultin in bootstrap.css u are adding in this

Answer (score 0):

Put `height:auto` for your page-wrapper

```
. page-wrapper {
    height: auto;
}
```

And for the body.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all set `min-height: 100%` to `body` and `html`.
If you want height in % then its parent should have some defined height, at the same time you want parent height to be auto then give `min-height:100%` to `parent` also, i.e, to `.page-wrapper`.
Now give `min-height: 25%` to child.

If you want `child` height to be restricted to `25%` only then give max-height also as 25% .

```
body, html, .page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%
}
.navbar-default {
  min-height: 25%
}
```